# Redirect to different domain if user is using Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I want to redirect a user to a different domain, but only when he's using Chrome. 
The new domain redirects to the same server as the old domain. Literally I just want to display a different domain, when a user is using chrome.

This is what I have came up with:

```
<script>parseInt(navigator.appVersion.match(/.*Chrome\/([0-9\.]+)/)[1]) >= 64 ? document.location = "https://newdomain.com" + window.location.pathname : true</script>
```

the problem with this script is, that when someone is using chrome and goes to my old domain it ends in a redirect loop and never stops. Can anyone help? I guess I need to specify somehow, that when the user is redirected to the new domain the script stops.

Comment: So just check what `location.host` or `location.hostname` contain, before you redirect …

Comment: @CBroe how can I do that inside of the script?

Comment: `navigator.appVersion.match(…) && location.host != '…' ? …`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need check browser type and current hostname before you decide to redirect, something like;

```
const isChrome = parseInt(navigator.appVersion.match(/.*Chrome\/([0-9\.]+)/)[1]) >= 64

if(isChrome && window.location.hostname != "YOUR_OLD_DOAMINNAME){
   document.location = "https://newdomain.com" + window.location.pathname
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a URL parameter that will stop the loop of redirection.

`"https://newdomain.com" + window.location.pathname + ?redirected=true`

You can read it and check if it was already redirected before.

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const redirected = new URLSearchParams(queryString).get('redirected');

if (!redirected) {
  // your code for redirection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks guys, its now working with this code:

```
const isChrome = parseInt(navigator.appVersion.match(/.*Chrome\/([0-9\.]+)/)[1]) >= 64

if(isChrome && window.location.hostname == "olddomain"){
     var newurl = location.href;
     newurl = newurl.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '')
     document.location = "newdomain" + newurl
}
```

The only problem I seem to face now is, that it also directs users who use microsoft edge because it uses the chrome user agent. But thats not really a big problem. 
I used location.href because when using location.pathname its not the full url.

So what this code does now, it first checks the user agent and if the user is using the Chrome browser. It then redirects the user to another domain that points to the same host as the old domain. The only thing that changes for the user is the domain.